# Visual Studio 2013 - Reuse current document window, if saved

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for the option 'Reuse current document window, if saved' as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z4b7zzx.aspx

My options menu shows every option featured on the msdn page except that one.

I'm using a german version of Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with update 4. I tried using different development settings but it still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this feature was removed in VS 2012 and not supported in VS 2013 as well. Probably due to the Preview tab introduced in VS 2012+.